# Interaction between caffeine intake and biorhythm on alertness

Tags: performance, attention, psychopharmacology, arousal

Throughout the day, people's wakefulness and attentiveness varies, as modulated by one's [circadian biorhythm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circadian_rhythm). Whereas in the morning people are less awake, just before noon and around 15:00 people appear to experience peak performance.

[image]

As nicely discussed in an older question, taking caffeine also seems to generally improve cognitive performance and alertness ([Does caffeine improve performance for habituated consumers?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/111/does-caffeine-improve-performance-for-habituated-consumers/136#136)).

I was wondering if these two factors may interact. For example, if you are in a "dip" in the circadian cycle, will coffee be most effective on attentiveness (because there is more room for improvement so to say)? Or will coffee be more effective when your are at a peak in the cycle, where the caffeine and the cycle amplify each other's effect?

**Is there any scientific literature that investigated the interaction between caffeine intake and the circadian cycle?**